# checkbutton is not checked by set the variable parameter, what's the reason?

Tags: tkinter

if I just run b function, it works fine, but when I try the code below, it seems to not work.

```
import tkinter as tk

def b():
    c = tk.Tk()
    x = tk.IntVar()
    x.set(1)
    tk.Checkbutton(c, variable=x).pack()
    c.mainloop()

# b()
a = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(a, command=b).pack()
a.mainloop()
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? There are no errors running both ways.

Comment: There is seldom a need for two `Tk` instances. Use `c = tk.Toplevel()` instead and remove `c.mainloop()`